# Extracting major semantic elements from stanford core nlp dependency representation

Tags: java, dependencies, nlp, stanford-nlp, semantics

I am a computer science student, now doing an NLP project. I have done a programme to convert a given input sentence in to dependency structure representation using the following code

```
    private void nextActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     
    Properties props = new Properties(); 
    props.put("annotators", "tokenize, ssplit, pos, lemma, parse"); 
    StanfordCoreNLP pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props, false);
    String text = input.getText();
    Annotation document = pipeline.process(text);
    for(CoreMap sentence: document.get(SentencesAnnotation.class))
    {   
         SemanticGraph dependencies = sentence.get(CollapsedDependenciesAnnotation.class);
         System.out.println(dependencies);
              }      

}
```

I am getting output for the given example sentence "**A cat is sitting on the table**" as shown in figure[-> sitting/VBG (root)  -> cat/NN (nsubj)    -> A/DT (det)  -> is/VBZ (aux)  -> table/NN (nmod:on)    -> on/IN (case)    -> the/DT (det)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FTmtN.png)
Now what I want is to retrieve major semantic elements from the given dependency representation. For example, in the given sentence i want to retrieve **sitting**, **cat** and **table** . That is for a general simple sentence, i want to retrieve the root word, subject and object.Anybody please help with example codes.

Answer (score 1):

For simple cases, you can define [Semgrex patterns](http://nlp.stanford.edu/nlp/javadoc/javanlp/edu/stanford/nlp/semgraph/semgrex/SemgrexPattern.html) over the dependency graph. For instance, to extract subject/verb/object triples you could use the code below:

```
SemgrexPattern pattern = SemgrexPattern.compile("{$}=root >/.subj(pass)?/ {}=subject >/.obj/ {}=object");
SemgrexMatcher matcher = pattern.matcher(new Sentence("A cat is sitting on the table").dependencyGraph());
while (matcher.find()) {
  IndexedWord root = matcher.getNode("root");
  IndexedWord subject = matcher.getNode("subject");
  IndexedWord object = matcher.getNode("object");
  System.err.println(root.word() + "(" + subject.word() + ", " + object.word());
}
```

Note that even your example isn't in this simple case though. You have an `nmod:on` edge rather than a `dobj` edge between *sitting* and *table*. As things get more complex, it might be worthwhile to take the Stanford OpenIE output at face value:

```
new Sentence("A cat is sitting on the table").openieTriples()
  .forEach(System.err::println);
```

This will get you a triple `(cat; is sitting on; table)`, and perhaps it's easier to post-process this into `(cat; sitting; table)` or whatever your actual downstream application is.